# Get MacOS process pid

Tags: c, macos, pid, macos-mojave

I am working on MacOs application. There I would need to get process pid. Is there any way to get that pid starting from bundle id or app name?
I am using C/C++ so Objective-c is not an option now
Thanks in advance

Comment: To be clear: are you trying to get the PID of the app itself, or of some other process?

Comment: Other process. To get mine I am aware of getpid function

Comment: Possible duplicates: [*How to get a list of all running processes on a Mac?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3334623/643383) and [*unable to detect application running with another user (via switch user)
*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18820199/643383)